# How to check if a string ends with an integer.

Tags: javascript, regex

please advice on how to check if a string ends with any integer at all in javascript. Not a specific integer.

e.g `aahdhs7; //Returns true`
`assa4; //also returns true`

Thank you

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Use regex. Consider trying something yourself.

Comment: Should `aargh4.6` return false?

Comment: @Zenoo I tried using endswith() , but it's only if i want to target a specific character.
I also researched on how to do it using regex, but i wasn't getting what i wanted, that's why i put it out here. Thanks for the downvote

Comment: @Teemu yes it should. I'm targeting mainly whole numbers
Thanks

Comment: Mhh ... `6` is an integer ..? And the accepted answer returns true from `aargh4.6`.

Comment: Just do `/\d/.test(str.slice(-1))` or `/\d$/.test(str)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regex to detect if last value is an integer:

```
^.*(\d)$
```

Example here - https://regexr.com/3mk0q

Comment: Thanks alot. It works :)

Comment: There's no point in `^.*` or grouping the `\d` just do `/\d$/.test(string)`

Answer (score 0):

try `Number.isNumber()`

```js
my_str = "Hi Hello 3";
my_str1 = "Hi Hello";

console.log(Number.isInteger(parseInt(my_str.substr(-1))));
console.log(Number.isInteger(parseInt(my_str1.substr(-1))));
```